# Is it possible to decrypt .seb file having password?

Tags: encryption, safe-exam-browser

My school started to use Safe Exam Browser as platform for online tests and i wanted to know more about it. I was trying to understand how its configuration file are made and what they actually contain, so i started to read the documentation from [here](https://safeexambrowser.org/developer/seb-file-format.html) in order to decrypt one of that, but i didn't manage to do it. Could you please give me an idea of the procedure to follow to dercypt a .seb file, assuming that it is possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SEB configuration file is generated by opening SEB client, adjusting the settings to one's liking and entering the password (or digital certificate), which encrypts the config file. When you open .seb file with SEB and enter the password (which must be provided by your school), the .seb file is "decrypted" and the SEB client is configured accordingly. Without the password, it is generally impossible to break the encryption (for more details see [Advanced Encryption Standard Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#Security)).

Although the .seb information can be extracted from SEB GUI settings plane, I am adding a Python script based on [this](https://github.com/SafeExamBrowser/seb-win/issues/73) thread. The complete encryption/decryption algorithm is described [here](https://safeexambrowser.org/developer/seb-file-format.html).

```py
import gzip
import zlib
import rncryptor  # https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor

# Modify the rncryptor post_decrypt_data class to fit the algorithm
class RNCryptor_modified(rncryptor.RNCryptor):
    def post_decrypt_data(self, data):
        data = data[:-(data[-1])]
        return data

def decrypt_SEB(password):
    cryptor = RNCryptor_modified()
    with gzip.open('encrypted.seb', 'rb') as f:
        file_content = f.read()
    decrypted_data = cryptor.decrypt(file_content[4:], password)
    decompressed_data = zlib.decompress(decrypted_data,15 + 32)

    with open("decrypted.seb", "wb") as f:
        f.write(decompressed_data)

decrypt_SEB("enter_password_here")
```

This reads the decrypted .seb file ("encrypted.seb") and outputs the decrypted XML ("decrypted.seb").

Comment: Thanks @Jan to answer me. I understand the process that SEB does when opening a .seb file, but my question, maybe not so clear, was another. I have the password of the .seb file and i would like to write a program to decrypt it, so i had to fully understand which are the steps that SEB follows when opening a config file. Is it possible? Or is there a more correct way to decrypt a .seb file?

Comment: @mattiamonari I have extended the answer with the python algorithm, which can be used to decrypt SEB file using python3.x.

Comment: Hi @Jan, do you have an idea instead on how to encrypt the .seb file? The main problem is that i don't know the administrator password (but i know the SHA-256 of it). Is there a way to encrypt it knowing just that? According to what SEB forum say, i should encrypt the gzip compressed XML settings data with that password and prefix it with “pswd”. Is there a way to do that knowing just the SHA-256 of the password?

Comment: I don't think you can do anything with SHA-256 of password... AES requires PBKDF2 algorithm, which uses actual password.